# Fluctuating accuracy for Naive Bayes Classifier and SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, accuracy, naive-bayes-classifier

I am comparing the classification accuracy between Naive Bayes (NBC), SVM and a Neural Network. I am using a Dataset of ~18K and 26 Labels.

In the current state the Neural Network get always an accuracy of >80%, but the NBC and SVM fluctuate between 15% and 80%. They mostly end up near one of the two extrema.
The only difference for each run is the splitting of the data in Training/Testing with the model_selection.train_test_split() function of sklearn

For the implementation of the classifiers I am also using the classes and functions of sklearn.

[image]
[image]

I highly suspect the problem in my data but I am already doing the basic preprocessing with stop words, lowercasing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the "stratify" attribute of the train_test_split function in order to have a good distribution of the classes (this will avoid the case where there is a support of 0 on the class number 25).

Finally, if you see a big variance depending on the dataset, I think a cross validation is interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The stratify parameter made it work.